# Links from workflow

Tags: links

We have a document library and department pages.  In the department pages we have links to documents in the library.  We also have a document approval workflow.   It's it possible to get the link created in the page once the final approval has been completed?

Thanks

Comment: Should you elaborate more what do you mean with link created within the page ?!!

Comment: Yes.  Each department has a page and on the page is a number of links to the corresponding document in the library.  Is it possible to have a step as part of the approval process to create a link in the department page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with OOTB Approval workflow, But you can do a a simple workaround to achieve that as the following:

- Create a custom view in your library to show only the approved document that related to this department.
- Edit your page and instead of adding the documents links manually, try to add a web part, add your document library ,
- Edit the web part and select your custom view to show only the document links that approved.